# Windows Server 2012r2 domain - cannot reach website (timeout)

Tags: networking, dns, windows-domain, timeout

I have a windows server 2012 r2 domain and it is functioning mostly normally, however one specific site fails to load (secure8.i-doxs.net [timeout]). This site responds normally from connections outside the network but none of the machines inside the network. The server returned the following on nslookup which I thought was suspicious

```
C:\Users\Administrator>nslookup secure8.i-doxs.net
1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa
        primary name server = localhost
        responsible mail addr = nobody.invalid
        serial  = 1
        refresh = 600 (10 mins)
        retry   = 1200 (20 mins)
        expire  = 604800 (7 days)
        default TTL = 10800 (3 hours)
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  ::1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    secure8.i-doxs.net
Address:  205.216.45.38
```

I have my Forward Lookup DNS as OpenDNS and Google. I have disabled Root Hints when no forwarder available. When I attempt to ping this site it times out. Other HTTP/HTTPS sites load just fine on the network.

Please help, I'm not sure where to look - thank you!

Comment: What are the contents of your `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file?

Comment: Hosts file is empty/default